# Extract the attribute names from a large number of Shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile, linux

I happened to need the attribute names of a large number of `.shp` files.
Is it possible under Linux, without importing the files into a GIS?

Comment: Uhm.. not sure: why the downvotes? Did I ask a "wrong" question?

Comment: Thanks, I see, even if I simultaneously answered my own question... Maybe it was the wrong way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a QGIS tag and in QGIS you can do:

```py
import os
shapefolder = r'/home/bera/GIS/ok_riks_Sweref_99_TM_shape/oversikt/riks/'

shapefiles = [os.path.join(shapefolder,f) for f in os.listdir(shapefolder) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(shapefolder, f)) and f.endswith('.shp')]

for shapefile in shapefiles:
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(shapefile, 'templyr')
    print(os.path.basename(shapefile)+' '+' '.join([f.name() for f in layer.fields()]))
```

Output:

```
al_riks.shp KKOD KATEGORI ADAT
nv_riks.shp KKOD KATEGORI NAMN1 NAMN2 ADAT
mb_riks.shp KKOD KATEGORI TATNR LANSKOD AREASCB BEF NAMN1 NAMN2 ADAT
hl_riks.shp KKOD KATEGORI NAMN1 NAMN2 ADAT
```

Comment: Thanks, that is useful if shapefiles have already been imported in QGIS. In my specific I was looking for a more generic method, to extract the attributes directly from files/archives, without prior import.

Comment: Nice. No you dont have to import anything, just change the shapefolder variable and run it.

Answer (score 3):

Under Linux, from the command line, one can neatly use `unoconv` to batch convert the associated `.dbf` files into `.csv` streams, pipe it through `head` and extract only the file name and the first line, which contains the headers:

```
apt-get install unoconv
ls -1 */*.dbf |xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c 'echo {};unoconv -f csv --stdout {}|head -n1'
```

The output will be similar to this:

```
shapefile_1/shapefile_1.dbf
"ID,N,16,0","NAME,C,40","ATTR1,C,8","ATTR2,C,8","ATTR3,C,8","ATTR4,C,16","ATTR5,C,25","ATTR6,C,22","ATTR7,C,66","ATTR8,C,20","ATTR9,N,16,5"
shapefile_2/shapefile_2.dbf
"AREA,N,19,11","ID,C,20","ATTR1,C,8","ATTR2,C,8","ATTR3,C,8","ATTR4,C,16","ATTR5,C,25","ATTR6,C,22"
shapefile_3/shapefile_3.dbf
...
```

If you want to have just the clean names (i.e. without the bdf type specifications):

```
ls -1 */*.dbf |xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c 'echo {};unoconv -f csv --stdout {}|head -n1'|sed 's/","/@/g'|sed 's/"$/@/'|sed 's/,[A-Z0-9,]*@/ /g'
```

which outputs:

```
shapefile_1/shapefile_1.dbf
ID NAME ATTR1 ATTR2 ATTR3 ATTR4 ATTR5 ATTR6 ATTR7 ATTR8 ATTR9
shapefile_2/shapefile_2.dbf
AREA ID ATTR1 ATTR2 ATTR3 ATTR4 ATTR5
shapefile_3/shapefile_3.dbf
...
```